# Setting a file to "Read-Only" in Windows with ICACLS

Tags: windows, icacls

I knew how to set a file Read-Only with `cacls`:

```
  cacls "toto.txt" //E //P Everyone:N
  cacls "toto.txt" //E //G Everyone:R
```

It removed all rights for everyone and then only added "Read" right.

How to do the same thing with `icacls`?

In particular, I tried:

- `icacls toto.txt /grant "everyone":R` but the file is still writable
- `icacls toto.txt /deny "everyone":W` but the file is not readable anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that access rights are inherited from the parent folder.

The following 2 lines will do the trick:

```
icacls toto.txt /inheritance:r
icacls toto.txt /grant "everyone":R
```

The first additional line will remove all inheritance.

Or even better, you could join them into a single line:

```
icacls toto.txt /inheritance:r /grant:r Everyone:R
```

Comment: When icacls denies "W", it also includes the SYNCHRONIZE right.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in icacls, to this day.  The same goes for making folders read only.  Denying "W" also denies the "SYNCHRONIZE" right.

You can see it with cacls:

```
Everyone:(DENY)(special access:)
                                    SYNCHRONIZE
                                    FILE_WRITE_DATA
                                    FILE_APPEND_DATA
                                    FILE_WRITE_EA
                                    FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES
```

To get the result you want, you have to specify those other 4 rights explicitly:

```
icacls toto.txt /deny "everyone":(WD,AD,WEA,WA)
```

And then cacls will tell you SYNCHRONIZE is no longer denied, and the file is still readable.

```
Everyone:(DENY)(special access:)
                                    FILE_WRITE_DATA
                                    FILE_APPEND_DATA
                                    FILE_WRITE_EA
                                    FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES
```

Icacls will give the *same output* after using either command, with or without synchronize:

```
Everyone:(DENY)(W)
```

See also this blog:  [I set the same ACL with the GUI and with icacls, yet the results are different](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20191118-00/?p=103110)

**NOTE** If you wonder what "Synchronize" does, here is a description:

> "**Synchronize**
>
> The Synchronize permission allows or denies different
>   threads to wait on the  handle for the file or folder and synchronize
>   with another thread that may  signal it. This permission applies only
>   to multiple-threaded,  multiple-process programs."

Furthermore, .*Net does not allow you to deny both write and synchronize.*  (Powershell).  Icacls does something that's not even allowed in .Net.  FileSystemAccessRights gets reduced to "Write" only.

```
New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(
  'Users','Write, Synchronize','Deny')

FileSystemRights  : Write
AccessControlType : Deny
IdentityReference : Users
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : None
PropagationFlags  : None
```

Comment: It’s unfortunate that this answer incorrectly states the behavior is a bug instead of intentional

Comment: @js2010 Thanks for addition. It seems Synchronize is mainly for multi-thread / multi-process so I will believe it is fine for me ;)

Comment: I see it as a bug, since the command makes OneDrive ran into sync problem.